# Specify charset in odbc for c++

Tags: c++, utf-8, character-encoding, odbc

I use "sql.h" libraries on windows for ODBC and I want to use the "utf-8" charset to read query results.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

ODBC doesn't use UTF-8, the API uses UCS2 or more recently with /some/ drivers UTF16. If you want UTF-8 encoded data you can decode the UCS2 and reencode it in utf8 or you can store utf8 encoded data in binary columns.

So you'll have to clarify what you mean by "use utf-8 charset to read query results".